# split and merge segmentation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Does anyone know of any implementation of Split and merge segmentation other than the following package (which is difficult to customize)?
http://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~lb/lb_downloads/

Comment: Better be moved to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Find out my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14730467/433685)! I have done a simple implementation in c++ with opencv. It is not super optimized but it seems to works. I followed the procedure described in [Gonzales's Digital Image Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201180758) book.