# scikit-image: segmenting an image into rectangles

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I would like to use *scikitimage* to segment an image into rectangles (where each rectangle color would be the mean color of the pixels composing this rectangle), it would look to something like this:

[image]

In Scikit-Image, there is the *slic* segmentation function that uses *k-mean* clustering, i.e, it will cluster all pixels that are neighbours and that are of similar color.

Here is an example with the corresponding code:

[image]

```
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.data import astronaut
from skimage.color import label2rgb
 

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
 

astronaut = astronaut()
 
# Applying Simple Linear Iterative
# Clustering on the image
# - 50 segments & compactness = 10
astronaut_segments = slic(astronaut,
                          n_segments=50,
                          compactness=10)
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
 

plt.imshow(astronaut)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
 
# Converts a label image into
# an RGB color image for visualizing
# the labeled regions
plt.imshow(label2rgb(astronaut_segments,
                     astronaut,
                     kind = 'avg'))
```

**So, my question is:** Is there a way to use one of the segmentation techniques offered by scikit-image to obtain this rectangle segmentation ? I have tried to see if one could change the *slic* function parameters in order to do that, but I could not find.

Best

Aymeric

Comment: you are looking for something like [split and merge](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1117%2F1.JEI.24.1.013007)

Comment: @Bilal thanks, is there not an existing Python library for this ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14730467) in `C++` you might find useful.